# Conditional scope on parent association to get all children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to fetch all the comments whom articles are published. So what scope definition will give me the results.
In articles model

```
has_many :comments
```

Comment model

```
belongs_to :article
```

Comment: `default_scope :publish, where(published: true)` `Article.publish.comments`

Comment: @RajarshiDas, it shouldn't be `default_scope`, just `scope`.

Comment: undefined method `comments' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xbce61c4>

Comment: `scope :publish_comments, includes(:article).where(published: true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define a scope in Comment model like this if you are storing published value in a boolean field

```
scope :having_published_articles, joins(:article).where("articles.published=?", true)
```

can replace published with column name that you are using.

Then to get all comments having articles which are published:

```
Comment.having_published_articles
```

Comment: use `includes` in spite of `joins`

Comment: @RajarshiDas: include must be used if associated articles are also required. But for only comments, joins should be used

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in all Ruby, without the string, it looks like this:

```
scope :having_published_articles, joins(:article).where(articles: { state: 'published' })
```